# Laravel : Variable layout for a single view

Tags: php, ajax, view, laravel

I wanted to know if there's a way to use variable layout for a single view in laravel.

I have a view of the login section. I want to show the login view in a lightbox by calling it via AJAX. I was thinking of using a different layout for the login view when it is called through ajax.
Something like this :

```
if($_GET["from"] == "ajaxLink") {
// use layout1
} else {
// use layout2
}
```

This obviously doesnt work. :)
Is there any way i can do this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways.

## 1. Blade layout

**Controller:**

```
$layout = Request::ajax() ? 'layout1' : 'layout2';

$data = array('layout' => $layout);

return View::make('index', $data);
```

**View:**

```
@layout($layout) 
//rest of the code....
```

## 2. Controller layout

```
public function action_index()
{
    $this->layout = Request::ajax() ? 'layout1' :'layout2';
    $this->layout->nest('content', 'index');
}
```

Comment: @itachi are you sure the controller layout method will work?  Don't you need to `View::make()` when you set `$this->layout` in an action?

Comment: @PhillSparks you don't need to `View::make` while using controller layout. the 2nd parameter in `$this->layout->nest()` points to the view file. and unlike other methods in laravel, the controller layout doesn't use `return`.

Comment: @itachi with L3 you need to use `View::make()` if you're setting it inside a controller action, it's only when you use `public $layout` that you don't need to `View::make`.  Take a look at the [Controller source](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v3.2.14/laravel/routing/controller.php#L62).